# Is there any way to remove the null values which I am getting in nested JSON objects in javascript or ES6

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

```
[ 
   { 
      "name":"FY20",
      "children":[ 
         { 
            "name":"Quarter1",
            "children":[ 
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"Quarter2",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Oct_fnfjnf 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"Quarter3",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Octfdmfj 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2015ldf_Oct 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"Quarter4",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2018_dfdct 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2018_fldfslt 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":"FY19",
      "children":[ 
         { 
            "name":"Quarter1",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Sep 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Nov 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"Quarter2",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2018_Dec 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Jan 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Feb 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Feb 06 Manual"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"Quarter3",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2019_March 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_April 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_May 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_May new_Manual"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"Quarter4",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Jun 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Jul 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":"FY18",
      "children":[ 
         { 
            "name":"Quarter4",
            "children":[ 
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"
               },
               { 
                  "name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Actually I want the above JSON object without null values through javascript or ES6

I tried search for lot of solutions but not able to find the correct solution for the nested loop, Please help by providing solutions or suggestions.

Thanks In advance

Comment: what should happen with `null` items in arrays? just filterd out?

Comment: yes Nicolas the values are filtering out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the data and `children` properties by checking the value.

This approach mutates the given data.

```js
const noNull = v => {
    if (v && typeof v === 'object' && Array.isArray(v.children)) v.children = v.children.filter(noNull);
    return v !== null;
};

var data = [{ name: "FY20", children: [{ name: "Quarter1", children: [{ name: "2018_Oct 17 Manual" }, { name: "2018_Oct 17 Manual" }] }, { name: "Quarter2", children: [null, null, { name: "2018_Oct_fnfjnf 17 Manual" }] }, { name: "Quarter3", children: [null, null, null, { name: "2018_Octfdmfj 17 Manual" }, { name: "2015ldf_Oct 17 Manual" }, { name: "2018_Oct 17 Manual" }] }, { name: "Quarter4", children: [null, null, null, null, null, null, { name: "2018_dfdct 17 Manual" }, { name: "2018_fldfslt 17 Manual" }] }] }, { name: "FY19", children: [{ name: "Quarter1", children: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { name: "2018_Sep 17 Manual" }, { name: "2018_Oct 17 Manual" }, { name: "2018_Nov 17 Manual" }] }, { name: "Quarter2", children: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { name: "2018_Dec 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Jan 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Feb 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Feb 06 Manual" }] }, { name: "Quarter3", children: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { name: "2019_March 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_April 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_May 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_May new_Manual" }] }, { name: "Quarter4", children: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { name: "2019_Jun 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Jul 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Aug 17 Manual" }] }] }, { name: "FY18", children: [{ name: "Quarter4", children: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { name: "2019_Aug 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Aug 17 Manual" }, { name: "2019_Aug 17 Manual" }] }] }],
    result = data.filter(noNull);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply map over the values recursively and at each level filter out the false/null values using `filter(Boolean)`.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "FY20",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Quarter1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "2018_Oct 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2018_Oct 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quarter2",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2018_Oct_fnfjnf 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quarter3",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2018_Octfdmfj 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2015ldf_Oct 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2018_Oct 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quarter4",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2018_dfdct 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2018_fldfslt 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "FY19",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Quarter1",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2018_Sep 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2018_Oct 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2018_Nov 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quarter2",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2018_Dec 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Jan 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Feb 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Feb 06 Manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quarter3",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2019_March 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_April 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_May 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_May new_Manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quarter4",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2019_Jun 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Jul 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Aug 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "FY18",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Quarter4",
        "children": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {
            "name": "2019_Aug 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Aug 17 Manual"
          },
          {
            "name": "2019_Aug 17 Manual"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

var newData = filterData(data);

function filterData(data) {
   return data.map(item => {
    if(item && item.children) {
      return {
        ...item,
        children: filterData(item.children)
      }
    }
    return item
   }).filter(Boolean)
}
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` values only seem to appear in a list and is quite easy to handle by simply converting your data to a string and replacing all occurrences of `null` with/without `,` with an empty string.

```js
const data = [{"name":"FY20","children":[{"name":"Quarter1","children":[{"name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"},{"name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"}]},{"name":"Quarter2","children":[null,null,{"name":"2018_Oct_fnfjnf 17 Manual"}]},{"name":"Quarter3","children":[null,null,null,{"name":"2018_Octfdmfj 17 Manual"},{"name":"2015ldf_Oct 17 Manual"},{"name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"}]},{"name":"Quarter4","children":[null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"2018_dfdct 17 Manual"},{"name":"2018_fldfslt 17 Manual"}]}]},{"name":"FY19","children":[{"name":"Quarter1","children":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"2018_Sep 17 Manual"},{"name":"2018_Oct 17 Manual"},{"name":"2018_Nov 17 Manual"}]},{"name":"Quarter2","children":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"2018_Dec 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Jan 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Feb 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Feb 06 Manual"}]},{"name":"Quarter3","children":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"2019_March 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_April 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_May 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_May new_Manual"}]},{"name":"Quarter4","children":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"2019_Jun 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Jul 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"}]}]},{"name":"FY18","children":[{"name":"Quarter4","children":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"},{"name":"2019_Aug 17 Manual"}]}]}];

const res = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/null,?/g, "");

console.log(JSON.parse(res));
```

Comment: Thanks you all for quick response and help, Very helpful and cleared my concepts, all solutions are working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Using **recursion**, and **filter**

```
const filterNulls = values => {
  return values.filter(value => {
   if (value && value.children) {
      value.children = filterNulls(value.children);
    }
    return value;
  });
};
```